# Limit daily quota of tickets by wordpress user

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So, basically I have one page where users can print a parking validation ticket, but they should be allowed only two times a day.

Is there any way that I can make an counter of sorts when button "print" is clicked to log it in DB and then if counter is > 2 in last day it disables that page and returns a message?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you give us more detail on how you are implementing this we can help more.

I'm sure you'll need to do it as a plugin and create an extra table on install. Here it's explained in detail in WP Codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

Then I'd create a function to add a new entry on that log table with the user ID and the date AND check how many rows I have for a given ID and date. Here's the WP Codex page for wpdb class to update the table: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

I'd call it from my custom.php file If the count is > 2, I'd use a different rendering sequence. Maybe divide the views in two and including them to make it more mantainable.

**edited**

Examples:

Create a table on activation:

```
function myPlugin_install() {
  global $wpdb;
  $tbl = $wpdb->prefix . 'myPlugin_log'; // Or anything you want

  $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tbl ......" // Define your table structure
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
  dbDelta( $sql ); // Use the upgrade API to create the table

}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__ , 'myPlugin_install' );
```

How to insert rows:

```
function logNewEntry() {
  global $wpdb;
  $tbl = $wpdb->prefix . 'myPlugin_log';
  $userID = get_current_user_id(); 
  $wpdb->insert(
    $tbl,
    // if you defined 'user' and 'time' as the fields to hold this info
    array( 'user'=>$userID, 'time'=>current_time( 'mysql' )  )
  );
}
```

Comment: Some actual code examples would be helpful. Your answer is just as vague as the question.

Comment: That's why I asked for more detail, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, without have to writing plugin or anything. I just made POST with this button, so it is trigger also, here is the actual code (assuming you already have db connection, and you created table, it's all in the template file that is called for this post type):

```
//start checking the DB
$bigBang = strtotime('-1 day');
$guyToKill = $username;
$fireStuff = "Select count(*) as c from wp_posjete_parking where thisGuy='$guyToKill' and thisDate>'$bigBang'";
$resultGotBack = @mysql_query($fireStuff);
$final = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultGotBack);

//kill old entries
$doomsDay = strtotime("-2 days");
mysql_query('delete from WP_TABLE_NAME where thisDate<$doomsDay');

//condition
if ($final['c'] > 2){
die ('<p style="color:red;font-weight:900;">Daily quata exceeded</p>'); //kill it
} else {
//your stuff here
echo "<p>You have done this " .$red['c']. " out of 2 times allowed.</p>";
    }

//trigger
<form method="post" action="">
<ingput name="triggerSomeStuff" value="Trigger" />
</form>

<?php if (isset($_POST['trigger'])) {

 $thisGuy = $username; //username got from WP 
 $thisDate = time();

$wpdb->insert('WP_TABLE_NAME',array( 'thisGuy'=>$thisGuy, thisDate'=>$thisDate),
array('%s', '%s')
);}
?>
```